# Multiple baking in blender breaks the gravity parameter and objects float in the air

Tags: python, blender

I am facing problem with baking in animation.

I have a rigid body container of passive type with collision shape of 'MESH', kept on top of a blender plane rigid body of similar properties that of the container.

I am then creating duplicate copies of another object and then dropping multiple such objects in the container.

I am then baking the animation and saving rendered images from different camera angles. This is happening in a loop . For the first bake baking is good and follows all the physics and gravity parameters.

For the subsequent baking the gravity parameter is not good, and objects are floating in the air. The collision parameter seems to work fine.

I have set the end-frame to be 250.

While going through the blender documentation and some blogs, I came to know, that baking utilises CPU compute, and the physics in blender starts to behave weird once the scale of objects drops below 20cm. My objects are above the mentioned scale.

Could someone please help me in resolving this issue.

The overall flow is working fine , just that when I do multiple baking, the gravity parameter is not good for subsequent bakes.

Comment: Do you bake the animation multiple times? Why?